# function dont see JSON object (java script, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
function json (url){
       $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
           return data;
       })
   }
```

this function don't see "data"

```
function MakeAlert(){
       data = json('action.php');
       window.alert(data.name);
}
```

this work:

```
  function json (url){
           $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
               window.alert(data.name);
           })
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) is asynchronous. It sends the request and returns immediately. Once the server responds (which might be a few seconds later) it invokes the `success` callback and that's why the `data` is accessible only inside this callback.

If you want to block the caller you could send a synchronous request (note that this might freeze the UI while the request is executing which defeats the whole purpose of AJAX):

```
function json(url) {
    var result = null;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            result = data;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function json (url){
   $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
       return data;
   })
}
```

You cannot use `return` here. You would return `data` the to anonymous closure function.

Your best shot is to use a `callback function` which should be applied when the `getJSON` success handler is executed.

```
function json (url, cb){
   $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
       cb.apply(null, [data]);
   })
}
```

**usage**

```
json('action.php', function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```